# Xamarin.Android Intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, intellisense

I'm testing out Xamarin.Android in Visual Studio 2010 and have noticed that I have no Android Intellisense when I'm working in an Android Layout (.axml) file. However, I do get Android Intellisense when I'm working in a .cs file.

**Example:**

Here is a screenshot of my Main.axml file that lives in my Layout directory. Notice how the intellisense doesn't contain anything within the Android namespace.

[image: No Android Intellisense example]

What do I need to do to get intellisense to display the Android namespace in a .axml file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Kannan Balasubramanian](http://blog.binarybits.net/?page_id=8) has posted an answer that worked for me ([Binary Bits](http://blog.binarybits.net/?p=503))

Here's Kannan's solution:

---

Most of the people who work with Xamarin’s Mono for Android in Visual Studio 2012 face a bug where Intellisense doesn’t work for AXML in source view.

One of the fix which worked for me is mentioned below.

1. Launch Visual Studio 2012
2. Open a solution with .AXML file in it
3. Now XML main menu should be visible on top
4. Open “Schemas…” menu
5. Sort by “File Name” column and see if “android-layout-xml” and schemas.android.com.apk.res.android” are there. If found, skip to step 13
6. If not found, go to “Program Files” if 32-bit system or “Program Files (x86)” if 64-bit system.
7. Then go to “\MSBuild\Novell” or “\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android”
   You should be able to see 2 files “android-layout-xml.xsd” and “schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd”
8. Copy these 2 files to “\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas”
9. Again open the “Schemas…” menu as mentioned in steps 3&4
10. Now click “Add…” button and add these 2 files which should be located as mentioned in step 7 & 8
11. Now restart visual studio and the XML editor for design layout should work fine with Intellisense
12. From step 5….
13. If above steps don’t work, then close the Visual Studio 2012.
14. Now open “Developer command prompt for VS2012″ under Windows programs menu.
15. Type “Devenv /ResetSettings” without quotes.
16. Launch Visual Studio 2012 and see if Intellisense works.
17. If still not working, better go to Xamarin  forums and post there.

---

Comment: Works like a charm with VS 2013

Comment: For those who couldn't solve it after trying this solution like me , just try to use Automatic Editor Selector like mentioned in this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23624307/1334958

Comment: Using your solution in VS2015 the main tags (e.g. "Button") are now supported by Intellisense, thank you!. However, the properties (e.g. "android:text") are still not there. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: These files have moved in recent versions of Xamarin. If you can't find them on your machine, try looking for them in C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin Studio\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\schemas

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the latest release Xamarin.Android 6.0.1 – this may have been resolved in this release