# Intellisense and color coding support for Visual Studio not working for .axml Layout Xamarin Mono Android

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, intellisense, xamarin

I have installed xamarin mono-android-4.4.54 ,Visual studio 2010 and windows xp 32bit
which is working perfectly except i didnt find intellisense  support in axml layout file. I have tried to open axml file in xml editor then intellisense starts working but the android designer disappears. I have also tried [Xamarin.Android Intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245308/xamarin-android-intellisense-not-working-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

Following steps will be help you.

1. open visual studio 2010
2. select tools
3. option
4. Text Editor
5. select file extension option and in extension textbox add:`axml` and select editor as `XML (Text) Editor`.
6. click Add button.

then its working.

Answer (score 0):

One of the latest Windows Updates disables intellisense on VS2010 (XP OS)
Did you check this?
[VS2010 Intellisense problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798270/vs2010-intellisense-problems)