# Don't have intellisense in axml Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android, xamarin

I don't have intelisense in visual studio (Xamarin).

I have tried to follow the steps on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245308/xamarin-android-intellisense-not-working-in-visual-studio-2010) post, but it didn't solve the problem.

THank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already tried the solution suggested in the post, then maybe you should give a try to:

1)Right click your .axml file

2)Click "Open with..."

3)Select "Automatic Editor Selector (XML)

I am not sure why but if you open it as an Android Designer (which is the default on my VS2013) and then go to the "Source" tab it doesn't work.

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Comment: this also fixes the issue (at least for me) where VS wouldn't search any axml files (IE: search || find/replace didn't work in axml)

Comment: Man , you are awesome !! I was suffering because of the missing search & find and replace capabilities :)